# HTML5 Video Not Working Suddenly, Worked Previously

Tags: html, css, html5-video

So I'm working on a personal portfolio, I have a video as the cover section. Previously the cover video worked without flaw. I tried changing the cover photo to something more dynamic and aesthetically pleasing, and that video didn't work. It displayed as a still image. I tried reverting the video and it still doesn't work. I doubt it's something with the code, because previously it worked, the only thing I changed was referencing a different video. I tried clearing all my browser data, cache, everything and it didn't work.

NOTE: It's also not the fact that it's localized, because that was how I previously called the video to the page and it still worked. And other projects I deployed had locally stored videos to an assets folder and they too, worked without flaw.

Here's my code (HTML and CSS) for the video section on my portfolio:

```css
.homepage-hero-module {
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1
}
.no-video .video-container video,
.touch .video-container video {
    display: none;
    z-index: -1
}
.no-video .video-container .poster,
.touch .video-container .poster {
    display: block !important;
    z-index: -1
}
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
    z-index: -1
}
.video-container .poster img {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1
}
.video-container .filter {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1
}
.video-container video {
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1
}
.video-container video.fillWidth {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1
}

.text-center{
  color: white;
}

.btn btn-outline-light btn-lg text-center{
    position: fixed;
    top: -100px;
    left: -50px;
}

.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}


.card-title{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-a">
<div class="homepage-hero-module">
    <div class="video-container">
            <div class="text">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <h2 class="text-center">Christopher Bacani</h2>
                    <p class="text-center">Full Stack Web Development | Mobile App Development | Marketing/Advertising</p>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg text-center" type="button">Learn More</button>
                        </div>
                </div>
        <div class="filter"></div>
        <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
         <source src="./assets/video/portfolio-cover-2.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

If anyone has any idea how to fix it, please help because I don't know what happened that suddenly the whole thing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This code of yours works properly after changing only the source for video link. When I checked with the locally stored videos, it also works fine. So, try to tackle that problem and confusions can be discussed through comments.

```
<div class="container-a">
<div class="homepage-hero-module">
    <div class="video-container">
            <div class="text">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <h2 class="text-center">Christopher Bacani</h2>
                    <p class="text-center">Full Stack Web Development | Mobile App Development | Marketing/Advertising</p>
                    <div class="wrapper">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg text-center" type="button">Learn More</button>
                        </div>
                </div>
        <div class="filter"></div>
        <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth" controls>
         <source src="https://archive.org/download/Popeye_forPresident/Popeye_forPresident_512kb.mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Chris Bacani I can help you more if you provide me the folder structure of your project.

Comment: I can send it to you in a bit. 

What's weird though is that it works without flaw in Safari, and at the moment, not having changed any code, it works periodically in Google Chrome.

Comment: you are not providing me your project folder structure

Comment: I actually figured it out. Chrome's new update disables any video it recognizes has audio. If you add muted to the class name it bypasses Chrome's new update and allows the content to autoplay.